# Superfish - No output

Tags: 7, navigation

Hi I can't get Superfish to output anything in Drupal 7 Zen Starterkit Sub Theme

I've done everything : Installed the Module For Superfish, Libraries, and jQuery Update, I've installed the Superfish Library, created a Menu, called the Menu in Superfish Module, but no output.

I've tried putting in snippets of code in the page.tpl to call the Superfish menu, but they only caused errors.

Please help.

View here http://www.cambrianvacation.co.uk/safeside

Ant:-)

Answer (score 0):

First off, super fish module doesn't require the jquery update module so uninstall it. It's a PIA module if you don't need it. Second, in the superfish settings, set it to render 1 block. Go to the blocks and find the super fish block. Edit that block and set it for whatever menu you would like to use it for and place it in a region.

Comment: Did all that still nothing.

Comment: I selected the wrong menu, I selected -----* instead of <*>in the menu-parent selection.[Solved] I am an idiot:-)